# can not make Caps Lock a Control key using setxkbmap

Tags: 13.10, keyboard-layout

I am running Ubuntu 13.10 and I want to make Caps Lock another Control key. I found that the easiest way was using setxkbmap. But the strange thing is that it resets itself to the default after 1 minute or so, could somebody help me?